# Selenium WebDriver - What is the way to find checkbox with @FindBy annotation?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, findby

I want to find this checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" ... />
```

what is way to use @FindBy annotation?

Can I find to use value=checkbox?

Comment: Please post the complete HTML representation of the element (better the complete page).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using cssSelector with @FindBy attribute. See [this](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBy.html)

```
@FindBy(css = "[type='checkbox']")
private WebElement foo;
```

But, as alecxe has mentioned this selector is not very stable and unique. In order us to help you, you need to provide more information.